# How to insert text inline of text inside textarea tinymce using jquery?

Tags: jquery, tinymce, append

Suppose i am writing sometext inside a textarea and I want to insert some text inline, inline of text, actually anywhere inline of text "NOT BEFORE" and "NOT IN LAST".

already used jquery().append() type methods.

Note i don't have any string to replace. i actually want to insert fresh text on white space  inline of text  right on cursor placement without affecting rest of the text formatting.

Right now i am using a jquery function and calling it using a button click and function i am using is specific for tinymce but it inserts the text in last or we can put brefore. but how to do it inline somewhere inside of text?

```
function insertelement(sometext){
               tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent(tinyMCE.get('content').getContent()+sometext);
}
```

I hope you got the question.

Comment: to change text in textarea you **have to** replace it value with the new one. to achieve your goal just save current value of textarea  in variable and add fresh text to the end and replace with current . the same about cursor position

Comment: isn't there any way to insert on white space on cursor position?

Comment: i got it guys.

Its simply

    tinyMCE.execInstanceCommand('content',"mceInsertContent",false,'text to insert');

Answer (score 1):

I advise you to change the editor iframe content directly.

To access the editor body you may call `tinymce.activeEditor.getBody()`

Now, you only need to find the postion to where you want to apply your new content and add it there (i.e. using jQuery):

```
var $body = $(tinymce.activeEditor.getBody());
$body.find('p:last').append($('<span>text blah blah</span>'))
```

Comment: In reading about 30 questions about this, THIS is the correct answer. THANK YOU!